# Scala printing uninitialised array

Tags: arrays, scala

Printing uninitialised array results in size of array,  how is this working ? I am iterating over all elements so I expect it to throw error (compile or runtime ) because there is no element to iterate over. To me this is leading error prone code but If this is language feature is there any advantage in this case ?

```
val array:Array[Int] = Array(5)
array.foreach(x => println(x))

Output : 5
```

Update:
It was confusing because Array(1, 2, 3) creates an array with elements 1, 2 and 3 while Array(1) declares array with 1 element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array(5)` isn't an empty 5-element array; it's an array whose only element is `5`. You're printing the `5`.

If you wanted to create a 5-element array, that would be `new Array(5)`. This array's elements will be initialized to `0` by default, so you'd see `0` 5 times with that array.

Comment: Unfortunately I can accept answer only in 9 minutes waiting for that!

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to create an Array that contains 5 elements with some default values, you can do something like:

```
> Array.fill[Byte](5)(0)
Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I am learning language and experimenting with these things and you got my intention right!